# How to add autocomplete and documentation to a custom language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, documentation-generation

I have built a new programming language. So far I have already completed the syntax highlighting and snippets using the [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets).

Now, I need to add autocomplete and documentation for over 40,000 functions in my language. Each function has a brief description that I would like to display when hovering over the function.

For example:

```
""" check if number is prime or not """
IsPrime(num:a)->bool;
.
.
.
```

Is there a way to efficiently add all these functions to the autocomplete feature in Visual Studio Code and have the documentation to appear when hovering over the function?

Comment: what format do you have information about your functions and their descriptions stored in? Can we assume that you have it in JSON / JS object format?

Comment: I have it database and I can make small programe to make it in almost any format.

Comment: you must add a `HoverProvider` and `CompletionItemProvider` to your extension